# Query Importrange in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Data Set 1

```
Date - City - Amount
01-06-2022 - Bangalore - 10
25-06-2022 - Chennai - 20
02-07-2022 - Bangalore - 10
```

I am using "`=query(IMPORTRANGE("URL","FY 22 - 23!A:I"),"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col2='Bangalore' and Col1>=01-07-2022")`"

But it's giving me an error.
Can someone help

Comment: Could you specify what error you're getting? Error messages are usually descriptive of where the problem may occur and give hints on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query-

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("URL","FY 22 - 23!A:I"),"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col2='Bangalore' and Col1>= date '" & Text(Date(2022,7,1),"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'")
```

Comment: Hey it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

={query(IMPORTRANGE("URL","FY 22 - 23!A:I"),"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col2 = 'Bangalore' and Col1>= Date '"&text("01-07-2022","YYYY-MM-DD")&"' ")}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).